# Cómo obtener el mes de una fecha en palabra, no en número

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo el siguiente `SELECT` que me muestra como resultado un id y el número de mes que corresponde a la fecha de recarga.

```
SELECT a.id_extintor, MONTH(a.fecha_recarga) from tb_extintores a
```

Lo que necesito es modificar ese select para que me muestre el mes en palabra (enero, febrero) no en número como actualmente lo hace (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar la función [`MONTHNAME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname):

```
SELECT a.id_extintor, MONTHNAME(a.fecha_recarga) from tb_extintores a
```

Sin embargo, dependiendo de cómo está configurado la variable sistema `lc_time_names` en tu MySQL, puede que el resultado no salga en español. Si es tu caso, entonces para forzar que salgan los nombres en español, tienes que especificar el lenguaje para la sesión usando la sentencia (Referencia: [MySQL Server Locale Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html)):

```
SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';
```

O sea, combinando las 2 sentencias puedes estar seguro de obtener los meses en español:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';
SELECT a.id_extintor, MONTHNAME(a.fecha_recarga) from tb_extintores a;
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://rextester.com/KCSY87994)

Answer (score 4):

Otra forma es usar la función [`ELT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_elt), con el conjunto de meses, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT ELT(MONTH(a.fecha_recarga), "Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre") 
       from tb_extintores a;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  case month(a.fecha_recarga) 
WHEN 1 THEN 'Enero'
WHEN 2 THEN  'Febrero'
WHEN 3 THEN 'Marzo' 
WHEN 4 THEN 'Abril' 
WHEN 5 THEN 'Mayo'
WHEN 6 THEN 'Junio'
WHEN 7 THEN 'Julio'
WHEN 8 THEN 'Agosto'
WHEN 9 THEN 'Septiembre'
WHEN 10 THEN 'Octubre'
WHEN 11 THEN 'Noviembre'
WHEN 12 THEN 'Diciembre'
 END mes , a.id_extintor  from tb_extintores a
where year(a.fecha_recarga) = year(curdate()) 
group by mes , Month(a.fecha_recarga)
ORDER BY Month(a.fecha_recarga)ASC;
```

Dejo otra alternativa por aquí..

Comment: como ocupar la misma consulta para consultar el año anterior igual?, me explico la misma consulta para saber el año 2020 y 2019...